# get a specific serial number of one of my servers from AD using ADcomputer and Get-CimInstance commands on powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, serial-number

I got all servers serial numbers using the below command:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object Name | 
Foreach-Object {
Get-CimInstance Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Select-Object PSComputerName,SerialNumber
}
```

but I failed to get s specific serial number of one server only

I tried to get a specific serial number but I failed , I expected to get serial number for one server I want

Comment: This doesn't look like (PowerShell) scripting issue but something with the particular server. Do you get an error? Is WinRM on? What happens when you try the command locally (on the server itself)?

Comment: the command I provided in my question work successfully but it gives me the serial of all servers I have from AD but I want to get s specific server serial number I changed the code but I still can't get it

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but instead of `-Filter *` you might do `-Filter 'name -eq "specific_server_name"'` where `specific_server_name` is the name of your "*specific server*".